# Including a large header to use an object as a default argument

Tags: c++, include, header-files, iostream, default-arguments

I'm developing a small library for use with command line applications. One of the features of this library is that it's main class can produce text in an ostream, as such:

```
#include <iostream>    

class MyClass {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;

    void printToStream(std::ostream& stream = std::cout)
    {
        stream << "a: " << a << " | b: " << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My question is regarding the use of std::cout as a default argument. 
It is there simply to make the library easier to use, as it is geared towards command line applications as I have said before, so most of the time the desired output should be the standard output, but in case the user needs a different output stream they can provide one themselves.

This is the only point in my library where anything from `iostream` is used, so I am wondering whether having such a default argument causes any efficiency loss. From what I understand, `iostream` is a behemoth, clocking in at over 25,000 lines of code, and it is being included rather gratuitously should a user be providing their own output stream.

Furthermore, I understand that the compiler is probably smart enough to not include anything from `iostream` in the final executable if `cout` ends up not being used here, but I would like to know the full impact of this inclusion in my library - and whether there would be a better way of implementing cout as a default argument without having the user build against `iostream` when not necessary to do so.

Comment: Instead of using the default argument you could use overloading? Have a `void printToStream(std::ostream& stream)` function and a `void printToStream()` function. But you'd still need to include iostream to get the definition of ostream.

Comment: I'm thinking if I could get rid of the need for `iostream` I could just include `ostream`, which is considerably smaller (and also has the declaration for `endl`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer: Probably not your most important decision when it comes to your programming efforts.

Much longer answer, which doesn't really tell you much more than above, but you may still find interesting, if you are that way inclined.

This is one of those questions that is HIGHLY dependent on how sensitive your environment is. If you are building for a system with 256KB of RAM, and you have to fit several applications, an operating system and a database engine into all of that, obviously, ever kilobyte of application space is precious. On the other hand, on my laptop or desktop machine, where the memory is counted in more megabytes than fingers on one hand, probably nothing at all to worry about. In a middle of the range system with a few megabytes of RAM, not your first priority for keeping code size down.

I quickly wrote two simple applications, using a single header file:

**myclass.h:**

```
#include <iostream>    

class MyClass {
public:
    std::string a;
    std::string b;

    void printToStream(std::ostream& stream = std::cout)
    {
        stream << "a: " << a << " | b: " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then one that "uses" the `printToStream`:

**uses.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    m.a = "Hello";
    m.b = "World";
    m.printToStream();
}
```

Size in g++ -O1: 3502 bytes, clang++ -O1: 4409

and one that doesn't use `printToStream`:

**nouse.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    m.a = "Hello";
    m.b = "World";
}
```

Size in g++ -O1: 2349 bytes, clang++ -O1: 2923

The size difference is about 1500 bytes with clang++ -O1 and 1200 bytes with g++ -O1. The overall code size is around 2.5-4KB, so it's about 30% of the overall size in this tiny example. Obviously, this is far from linear - once you use `std::cout`, the initialization is there for all uses of it.

If I modify the `myclass.h` file to `#include <string>`, and remove the references to stream altogether, it further removes about 300 bytes of code from the `nouse.cpp` generated binary. This shows that JUST including `<iostream>` will add some code to your binary. However, using `<ostream>` instead of `<iostream>` makes no difference to the produced binary.

I also tried removing the `std::cout` default argument. That made no difference at all (except for code changes to have the additional argument in `uses.cpp`), so size is identical. It also has no effect on `nouse.cpp` - the extra code is still there to initialize `cout`.

Likewise, including `<ostream>` and then including `<iostream>` in the main file makes no difference to the size of `uses.cpp` (not using default argument).

I tried -O2 as well, and it makes the code change size (bigger in g++, smaller for clang++), but the relative difference isn't very big.

Obviously, this is for two instances of the two most popular open-source C++ compilers. Other compilers will probably give slightly different results. If it's very important, test with your compiler.

Version of g++: 7.2.0 as supplied with Ubunt, clang++: 7.0.0 (built from sources with git versions clang 16003bcdb4287aab3b87300d9e95f9b49ce52c1c, llvm  45ebd75cc103838da0b3938ac5d044ec8a7ff17b)